# .NET Structs that can be assigned constant values directly like built-in types

Tags: .net, struct

Can you make a struct that behaves like one of the built-in classes where you can assign the value directly without calling a property?

ex:

```
RoundedDouble count;
count = 5;
```

Rather than using

```
RoundedDouble count;
count.Value = 5;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do this via the [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) keyword.

For example, in your case, you'd want something like:

```
public static implicit operator RoundedDouble(double value)
{
     return new RoundedDouble(value);
}
```